# ios swift 3 building a bottom tab bar for custom keyboard

Tags: ios, swift3, keyboard, custom-keyboard

I am very new to swift 3 and ios development in general. I got the basic custom keyboard showing up on my device. however, the very first step is to now build a footer area with following things:

a button (to switch keyboard), a tab showing some custom stuff i am aiming for (consider blank tab for now) and another tab to show a regular keyboard.

Questions:

1. Do i have to build the regular keybaord from scratch ?
2. how to build this footer bar itself?

I was seeing creating a simple button is like hell 10 lines of code

```
func createButton(){       
    button = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 44, height: 44))
    button.setTitle("Get Quote", for: .normal)
    button.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ratingButtonTapped), for: .touchUpInside)
    view.addSubview(button)
    button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints =  false;
    button.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor, multiplier: 0.6).isActive = true
}
```

i will be dead creating the whole footer bar and the regular keyboard. please advise

Comment: can you explain what do you mean by "switch keyboard"?

Comment: well there is a mandatory requirment from apple to let user to go to other available keyboards on the device. so this is already there. i just need to know how to design a footer bar and put on it,

Comment: I am not sure if you can add a footer on the keyboard, but sure you can add a toolbar on top of it.. check @PuneetSharma answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Question 1: Yes, you have to since apple doesnt provide the native keyboard to use. However there are plenty Custom keybpard open source you can built on top them. This is one of them I used in the past : https://github.com/archagon/tasty-imitation-keyboard

Question 2: Footer bar is a normal UIView, just like you build a UIView in a normal application

Hope this helps!

Comment: this is in swift 2 and trying to migrate to swift 3 gives weird errors

Comment: Yeah I used it a year ago I remember it was swift 2. But I converted it recently to swift 3 using the automatic convert tool by xcode, and commented out the lines causing errors that were not resolved. It worked perfectly. Please try that and get to me